Brother MFC-L2820DW ejects three blank pages on startup
I have a new Brother printer, and after installing it prints and scans great.  The problem is, after shutting itself down, when I restart it, it ejects three blank pages.  This has been going on for several days, and I am at a loss as to the reason.  Has anyone else every heard of this?  Thanks for ideas or answers.

Check the print queue before shutting down.

The print queue is empty prior to shutting down, however when I turn the printer back on, three jobs briefly appear.  The user printing shows as SYSTEM, and I am unable to delete them.  After the three pages eject, the three jobs disappear.  This happens every time.  If I unplug the USB from the computer, when I re-plug, the same thing happens with the three pages.  I am now of the opinion that the computer is at fault not the printer..

I connected my laptop to the printer, and nothing happens, however as soon as I plug it back into the main computer, immediately three blank pages are 'printed'.   I have checked everywhere on the computer and see no pending jobs anywhere.  I have checked all queues and the windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS folder and it is empty.  Of course, multiple restarts of the computer, too.
